# SyntaxError when using Jupyter on Python

Tags: python, syntax-error, jupyter

I installed jupyter package for Python but when I try to use it, I get SyntaxError : invalid syntax.

I tried to remove Python and reinstall it but I got the same result.

I use Windows 10, and Python 2.7.13
If more information are needed, please, ask.

```
Python 2.7.13 (v2.7.13:a06454b1afa1, Dec 17 2016, 20:42:59) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import jupyter
>>> jupyter notebook
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    jupyter notebook
                   ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: you should try calling `jupyter notebook` directly from the terminal, not from within python

Comment: [More information on starting jupyter](https://jupyter.readthedocs.io/en/latest/running.html#starting-the-notebook-server)

Comment: @dangom thanks man , it finally worked

Comment: Got this because I had a space at the end i.e. "jupyter notebook " - others beware if you get this and you are actually in the terminal ha!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To start jupyter just type (as you did):

```
jupyter notebook
```

In any **terminal** of your choice.

For example, in Windows, go to the Command Prompt, which looks like this:

[image: cmd]

(as you are in Windows 10 just search cmd with the start menu and press enter)

...and type that, you don't use IDLE (Python) or any other IDE to start it.

---

If you don't want to go to the cmd each time you want to open the jupyter notebook, just create a shortcut, and when this window comes up:

[image: Window]

... you have to type `jupyter notebook` and then next, then it will ask you to give the shortcut a name, call it whatever you want and finish. And now you will be able to double click an icon and your browser will come up as it should.